# query to linq based on time interval

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

Data contains entries for every minute, but I only need data for every 5 minutes, for example:

My current data:

```
[12:00, 12:02, 12:03, 12:04, 12:05, 12:06, 12:07, 12:08, 12:09, 12:10, 12:11, 12:12, 12:13, 12:14, 12:15, 12:16, 12:17, 12:18, 12:19, 12:20]
```

my goal is:

```
[12:00, 12:05, 12:10, 12:20,]
```

my linq :

```
    public ActionResult GetData()
    {

        FireViewModel _fireViewModel = new FireViewModel();
        var query = (from w1 in db.V_PDCPowerDemandArchiveForMis
            where db.V_LastEafHeat.Any(w2 => w1.DATE >= w2.StartTime)
            orderby w1.DATE descending
            select w1).Take(20).ToList();

        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            _fireViewModel.Power.Add(item.EAF1);
            _fireViewModel.Date.Add(item.DATE.ToShortTimeString());
        }

        return PartialView("_Fire",_fireViewModel);
    }
```

Comment: Is it just dates, or is there some data associated that you need to avg or sum?

Comment: You need to do a better job with showing relevant code and related data types. That said, the idea for your solution is simple: Write a function that will map your time-series data into appropriate buckets. Once you have this mapping, you can simply use this function in your `GroupBy` call

Comment: yes, there is a property, it is calling Power property. the power value depends on date value

Comment: This isn't entirely clear, but it looks like you need to filter on a 'minutes is multiple of 5' predicate, like: 'where w1.Minute % 5 == 0'.

Comment: yes the key is i've should do  w1.Minute % 5 == 0

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you want to achieve is to group your records so that you can find the ones who belong to the 12:00 to 12:05 range, the ones who belong to the 12:05 to 12:10 range, etc.

Then you need to replace the minute part of your time by 00, 05, 10, etc. 
You can do this by doing a round. Cast the second part as float, and divide by 5: 02 becomes 0.4, 08 becomes 1.6, etc. Then round to the next integer with ROUND(n,0) and 0.2 becomes 0 while 0.8 becomes 2. Once this is done, multiply by 5 and you get your numbers jumping from 5 to 5. See example below

```
DECLARE @Nu TABLE (valsec CHAR(2), valfloat FLOAT)
INSERT INTO @Nu (valsec) VALUES ('01')
INSERT INTO @Nu (valsec) VALUES ('02')
INSERT INTO @Nu (valsec) VALUES ('03')
INSERT INTO @Nu (valsec) VALUES ('04')
INSERT INTO @Nu (valsec) VALUES ('05')
INSERT INTO @Nu (valsec) VALUES ('06')
INSERT INTO @Nu (valsec) VALUES ('07')
INSERT INTO @Nu (valsec) VALUES ('08')
INSERT INTO @Nu (valsec) VALUES ('09')
INSERT INTO @Nu (valsec) VALUES ('10')
INSERT INTO @Nu (valsec) VALUES ('11')
INSERT INTO @Nu (valsec) VALUES ('12')
INSERT INTO @Nu (valsec) VALUES ('13')
INSERT INTO @Nu (valsec) VALUES ('14')
INSERT INTO @Nu (valsec) VALUES ('15')
INSERT INTO @Nu (valsec) VALUES ('16')
INSERT INTO @Nu (valsec) VALUES ('17')
INSERT INTO @Nu (valsec) VALUES ('18')
INSERT INTO @Nu (valsec) VALUES ('19')
INSERT INTO @Nu (valsec) VALUES ('20')
UPDATE @Nu SET valfloat = CAST (valsec AS FLOAT) / 5
SELECT 
    valsec,
    valfloat,
    ROUND (valfloat,0)*5 AS secint,
    RIGHT (CAST (( ROUND (valfloat,0)*5 + 100) AS VARCHAR(3) ),2) AS secchar
FROM @Nu
```

Result:

```
01  0.2 0   00
02  0.4 0   00
03  0.6 5   05
04  0.8 5   05
05  1   5   05
06  1.2 5   05
07  1.4 5   05
08  1.6 10  10
09  1.8 10  10
10  2   10  10
11  2.2 10  10
12  2.4 10  10
13  2.6 15  15
14  2.8 15  15
15  3   15  15
16  3.2 15  15
17  3.4 15  15
18  3.6 20  20
19  3.8 20  20
20  4   20  20
```

Note: the section

```
RIGHT (CAST (( ROUND (valfloat,0)*5 + 100) AS VARCHAR(3) ),2)
```

only converts the number into a char(2) by addding 100 and taking the last two characters (so that you get 05 instead of 5)

Answer (score 0):

the key is w1.Minute % 5 == 0 i should put a condition in foreach like this:

```
 public ActionResult GetFuranceOne()
    {
        FireViewModel _fireViewModel  = new FireViewModel();

        var query = (from w1 in db.V_PDCPowerDemandArchiveForMis
                     where db.V_LastEafHeat.Any(w2 => w1.DATE >= w2.StartTime)
                     orderby w1.DATE descending
                     select w1).Take(50);


        foreach (var item in query.ToList())
        {
            if (item.DATE.Minute % 5==0)
            {
                _fireViewModel.Power.Add(item.EAF1);
                _fireViewModel.Date.Add(item.DATE.ToShortTimeString());
            }
        }
        return PartialView("_Fire", _fireViewModel);
    }
```